# gmap marker with label

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map which was working well until a few days ago.

My problem is that now, all the label markers appears in the right place but only the last image appears.

I see in the generated html code that all images are here but all of them have the same position (that's why i can just see the last one).

here i am using gmap version 3.3

actually it was working before, i'm sure! Maybe google has changed something (i'm calling the src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.3).

because when i removed markerwith label and used simple markers without label then all markers are seen.     function

```
addMarker(location,vehno,vehid,drvId,drvName,phoneNo,content,gId,a,marker_img){    
  var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
      marker_img,
      null,
      null, 
      null, 
      new google.maps.Size(32, 32)
  );   

  //if(cursel==-1)
    var labelcontent = "<b>"+vehno+"/"+vehid+"</b>";       
  var mflag = 0;  

  var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: location,
       icon:pinIcon,               
       map: map,                                              
       title:vehno, 
       labelContent: labelcontent,
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", 
       labelPosition:location,
  });
```

Comment: Without any code it might be hard to help you...

Comment: src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.3

Comment: That's Google's code. I meant your code.

Comment: i have code about 2000 lines, hope this is sufficient actually ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setting library link to following fixed problem
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `MarkerImage` was deprecated in version 3.10 of the maps API. The new way is to use a plain object literal with the same parameters.

```
var image = {
  url: place.icon,
  size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
};
```

Concerning your problem, I suspect that you you shouldn't pass in `null` for the parameters you don't need.

```
var pinIcon = {
  url: marker_img,
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32)
};
```

This shoud use the default values for `anchor` and `origin`.

Comment: thank you hennes for help...but problem is still arriving.I think Problem is not with marker image,because when i added comments to icon parameter of markeroption then also same problem is arriving with default gmap red marker icon

Comment: Just to clarify, all the labels appear in the right position but all the marker icons appear in one and the same position even if you don't specify the `icon` parameter?

Comment: Dear hennes it seems that all markers are present on map,but all of them taking same location i.e position of last marker..

Comment: yes yes you are right..labels are at right position but marker icon appearing on single location value of last marker

Comment: @vijay I assume you have verified that the value of the `location` parameter is different for all of the markers? Could you add a `console.log(location)` at the start of `addMarker` and check the output?

Comment: yes all markers have its own location

Comment: @vijay Just to make sure, have you verified that `location` is a valid `LatLng` object on the console?

Comment: Thank hennes relpacing src to http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js solved problem,Can you tell me what was the issue.Because everything is working fine before two days

Comment: @vijay Seems to be Google internal then. No idea what went wrong. Glad you resolved it anyway.